# Accessing AWS EC2 from behind a company firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a beginner using AWS EC2 sercices. During the weekend, I managed to set-up EC2 instances, using security groups, connecting using Putty, ...

I come this monday at work and I can't connect anymore to an EC2 instance. I imagine this is linked to a company firewall rule.

I am feeling this is due to port 22 being blocked for SSH by my company firewall. And apparently I can't change port 22 for SSH during the set-up of security group.

So, what can I do ? Knowing that I would like to avoid the need to rely on the IT folks of my company, this takes forever.

Comment: I strongly advise not to try to circumvent company IT security policies... just talk to your IT folks or your manager.

Answer (score 1):

> I come this Monday at work and I can't connect anymore to an EC2
>   instance. I imagine this is linked to a company firewall rule.

A company firewall may not be the only reason, there might be the chance that your security group only Allow traffic from the home network? Go to EC2 instance and verify the Security Group.

Second thing try to ssh from other network or verify from IT team regarding term and policy so you should aware why the 22 is being blocked.

A very clear [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253591/ssh-into-a-remote-server-but-my-organization-has-blocked-port-22) about this approach but it does not mean to violate the **company policy and rule** just discuss these approach with your Network Team.

**DISCLAIMER:**

> All the option below, **can lead you to be fired for
>   violating your organization security policy.** If there is a Network
>   Administrator that is constantly checking for abnormal traffic peaks
>   and patterns, you could be caught. If you don't want to follow the
>   path of making a technical kludge to get the access,
>
> - Option 1: Put ssh to listen on a different port.
> - Option 2: Redirect the traffic incoming from another port to
>     tcp/22(ssh)
> - Option 3: Use [shellinabox](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox) to make a remote web terminal.AVOID USING
>     HTTP. Use a certificate as explained at the shellinabox manpages, even
>     if it is self-signed.
> - Option 4(non-root solution): Pay for a simple server at a cloud
>     provider(one that costs 5-10US$ month) to have a ssh jumpbox.